# Three.js - Cannot get custom object to load to browser using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am trying to load a custom .obj file to the ObjectLoader in Three.js. I am not able to figure out how to get the .obj file to be imported/used in my main.ts file. I am able to load Three.js geometries and I am able to load .obj files when I use an http request like 'https://url/myObject.obj' so I am thinking this is me doing something incorrectly with typescript. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import './styles/css/app.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'


const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF)
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: <HTMLCanvasElement> document.querySelector('#app__bg'),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(30);


scene.add(torus);


let loader = new OBJLoader();

loader.load('test.obj', function(object) {
        scene.add(object);
    }
)

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    torus.rotation.x += 0.01;
    torus.rotation.y += 0.01;
    torus.rotation.z += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate()
```

Comment: Are you setting up a localhost server? Have you read ["How to run things locally"](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) in the docs?

Comment: @Marquizzo I am using Vite and I am running that to start up my server. If I use VScode's live server I get "TypeError: 'video/mp2t' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type."  Vite appears to give me a working server on localhost but this is my first time using Vite so I may be running in to issues with that

Comment: It sounds like this problem doesn't have anything to do with Typescript. You may be pointing the address of `test.obj` to the wrong subfolder, or maybe Vite is moving that asset to serve from another location. I've never used Vite, so you may have to dig through their docs to find how it serves assets. Try to find it first by visiting `localhost:xxxx/path/to/test.obj`.